# Java Regex for PO Box Validation

Tags: java, regex

I am using following regex for PO BOX pattern validation -

```html
"([\\w\\s*\\W]*(P(OST)?.?\\s*((O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\\s*(B(IN|OX|.?))|B(IN|OX))+))[\\w\\s*\\W]*"
;
```

Here is some test result -

PO Box : Valid
P O Box : Valid
P. O. Box : Valid
P.O.Box : Valid
Post Box : Valid
Post Office Box : Valid
Post Office : Invalid
P.O.B : Valid
P.O.B. : Valid
POB : Valid
Post Office Bin : Valid
Box : Invalid
Bin : Invalid
Post : Invalid
Postal Code : Invalid
100,, P O Box Des Moines : Valid
 P O Box DesMoines1000 : Valid
 P O Box Des Moines 1000 : Valid
 Post Office Box : Valid
 Post Office Box   : Valid
Post Box # : Valid

However, this is validating **Hope Bulevard** or **Pablo Avenue** as valid PO BOX pattern. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the valid PO BOX pattern?

Comment: Here are few test results - 

PO Box : Valid
P O Box : Valid
P. O. Box : Valid
P.O.Box : Valid
Post Box : Valid
Post Office Box : Valid
Post Office : Invalid
P.O.B : Valid
P.O.B. : Valid
POB : Valid
Post Office Bin : Valid
Box : Invalid
Bin : Invalid
Post : Invalid
Postal Code : Invalid
100,, P O Box Des Moines : Valid
 P O Box DesMoines1000 : Valid
 P O Box Des Moines 1000 : Valid
 Post Office Box : Valid
 Post Office Box   : Valid
Post Box # : Valid

Comment: Add them to your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because a dot matches any character. You want to use `\.` to match a literal dot.

```
"([\\w\\s*\\W]*(P(OST)?\\.?\\s*((O(FF(ICE)?)?)?\\.?\\s*(B(IN|OX|\\.?))|B(IN|OX))+))[\\w\\s*\\W]*"
```

Also it looks utterly complicated to me. And it allows still too many strings. You have the 'box' duplicated, it therefore matches 'PBINBIN'.

Also you do not need the leading and trailing part.

```
"(P(OST)?\\.?\\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?\\.?\\s*B(IN|OX|\\.?))"
```

This pattern is still very permissive and allows quite strange ways to write 'PO BOX', like 'POST.  OFF B'. You should probably look through the data and match only orthographs that really appear.

To be sure that POB is not part of another word, you should use word delimiters. Usually it is `\b`, but I'm not sure that it is the same in Java.

```
"\\b(P(OST)?\\.?\\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?\\.?\\s*B(IN\\b|OX\\b|\\.?))"
```

A general remark : it seems that you write code by trial and error. This is a bad programming principle. When you approach a heuristic problem like this one, where there are necessarily false positives and false negatives, you have to weigh the cost of both, and then start with the simplest solution until the false results fall under the acceptable level.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz. I am trying out the solution you provided and It's showing invalid escape sequence error on Java editor.

Comment: I think it is because I didn't double the backslashes.

Comment: Lorenz, I tried your solution and it appears that it's not validating any address anymore. Here is an out put - 
Hope Bulevard : Invalid
Avenue PMB : Invalid
Pablo Avenue : Invalid
P.O. Box 123 : Invalid
Box : Invalid

Comment: Hi Lorenz, I think I am pretty close to solve this.
I used - 
"([\\w\\s*\\W]*(P(OST)?\\.?\\s*((O(FF(ICE)?)?)?\\.?\\s*(B(IN|OX|\\.?))|B(IN|OX))+))[\\w\\s*\\W]*"

Only issue I am having where follwoing checks are failing - 

Cam**pb**ell 
**P B**rowley
Cam**p B**etty
He**pb**urn

Comment: I also tried following regex - 

**([\\w\\s*\\W]*(P(OST)?\\.?\\s*((O(FF(ICE)?)?)?\\.?\\s*(B(IN|OX)))))[\\w\\s*\\W]***


This resolves the previous issues such as 

Campbell 
P Browley 
Camp Betty 
Hepburn 

However, it causes another issue. Now the validation fails for - 

P.O.B 
P.O.B. 
POB

Comment: I notice that you do not require a number after POB. Is this intended?